# Read a signed integer of 24 bit on Dart

Tags: java, dart, byte, 24-bit

I need help to read data from an external device. In the specifications is written that every single fetched value is a 24bit signed integer, but I can't correctly read data from Dart (while I can on Java).

Starting from Java (just because it works), I fetch the data as a byte array, then reading a byte give me the correct value:

```java
 byte[] data  = call.argument("mydata");
 Log.d("CONVERT_DATA_datai", String.valueOf(data[4]));
```

In this case, the output is `-1` and it's correct.

In Dart i've seen that there isn't a byte array type but I should use a `List<int>` instead, so my code is:

```dart
 List<int> data = value as List<int>;
 print(data[4].toString());
```

In this case I get the value `255` which is incorrect, I think because I've to convert it to signed 24bit integer.

Other samples are:

`-6` in java, `250` in dart (incorrect)

`3` in java, `3` in dart (correct)

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [`int.toSigned`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/int/toSigned.html) method might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is `Int8List` type in `dart:typed_data`.

And by accessing `Int8List::buffer` you can read any number you want.